# How to call javafx from a normal java class

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I want to call/open gui/fxml file from a normal class, i'm really having difficulties in finding a way to do this, I've try to instantiate the controller class but i'm not getting start function, Is it even possible to do what i'm trying to do?

normal class

```
    public class ReadXMLFile {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {

    }


}
```

fxml document

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="442.0" prefWidth="449.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="gis_map.CitizenScheduledController">
   <children>
      <TableView layoutX="1.0" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="384.0" prefWidth="447.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="CitizenId" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Address" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Arrival" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Departure" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Actions" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button layoutX="373.0" layoutY="396.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Approve" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

controllerClass

```
    package gis_map;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;


public class CitizenScheduledController implements Initializable {


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Comment: In case you want to open gui in some cases and otherwise let the program be the program you could try to split the main function which contains the launch call from the application class, so you could create the application class and launch it on need

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

No (at least, not easily, or in a way that makes sense).

The lifecycle of a JavaFX application is controlled by an instance of the `Application` class. Furthermore, you need to start the JavaFX toolkit and set the FX application thread running. The static  `Application.launch(...)` method accomplishes this, as well as creating the required instance of your `Application` class and calling the appropriate lifecycle methods on it.

So, just follow the standard pattern and make your `ReadXMLFile` class into a subclass of `Application`, make the `main(...)` method just call `launch()`, and define the `start()` method to load the FXML, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness:

Starting with JavaFX 9 it's possible to start up a application without relying on `Application.launch`. You can use [`Platform.startup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#startup-java.lang.Runnable-) for this purpose. Note that you're only allowed to use `Platform.startup` and/or `Application.launch` once in your application.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Platform.startup(() -> {
        // display empty scene after startup
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    });
}
```

It's usually better to use the normal application lifecycle and use a class extending `Application` as entry point and use the `init`/`start` methods for any initialisations you'd usually do from the `main` method.